# Trying to find .exe over multi drive wide search in a bat file. Tried with relative path commands

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

As stated in the title I have a bat file set up to locate and run 2 separate exe's. One is located in the same folder as the bat file which for this %~dp0 works just fine. The second exe is one to a game which is in whatever folder people decided to install it even in a different drive. I'm trying to find a way to call to that exe and launch it without it needing to be inside the same folder.

```
title Genshin Impact + ReShade
color 0f
mode con:cols=110 lines=25

REM ====================================================================================================
cls
REM ====================================================================================================
set "GenshinImpactPath=C:\Program Files\Genshin Impact\Genshin Impact game\GenshinImpact.exe"
start "" "%~dp03DMigoto Loader.exe"
REM ====================================================================================================

powershell -command Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
powershell -command Start-Process -FilePath Injector.exe GenshinImpact.exe -Verb RunAs
powershell -command Start-Process -FilePath '%GenshinImpactPath%' -Verb RunAs
powershell -command Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Restricted

exit
```

Right now it sets a path and then calls from it through powershell, I'm just hoping to find a better way to set the path so the game can be installed on any drive. Thank you in advanced for any help!